# Title-case words that are separated by underscores

Tags: php, string, title-case, humanize

I'm trying to transform a string to TitleCase before inserting it into my database. I'm using `ucwords`.

My strings are like: `FIRST_SECOND_THIRD`

My code:

```
if (//something){
    $resp = strtolower($line[14]);
    $resp_ = ucwords($resp, "_");

    //rest of the query...

}
```

`var_dump($resp_)` returns `null` and I have no idea why.

Comment: should work : https://3v4l.org/nXgvM

Comment: Strange, `var_dump(ucwords(null, "_"));` returns an empty string

Comment: The 2nd parameter of ucwords() is not supported in the versions below 5.5.16 ..

Comment: what PHP version are you using? According to PHP changelogs, the optional `delimiter` parameter was added on 5.4.32 for PHP 5.4 and 5.5.16 for PHP 5.5 and above

Answer (score 1):

**This do exact same thing, Hope will help, cheers.**

// php script

```
<?php

    $string = "FIRST_SECOND_THIRD";

    $var = strtolower(str_replace('_',' ',$string)); 
    $temp = ucwords($var);
    echo str_replace(' ', '', $temp);

?>

//output 
FirstSecondThird
```

the work could be little easier if the *custom delimiter* would have worked for the ucwords functions.

Answer (score 0):

If your input strings are fully uppercase, then your intention is to use `strtolower()` on the letters that **follow the letter** that is either at the start of the string or following an underscore.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6ppKZ))

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '~(?:^|_)[A-Z]\K[A-Z]+~',
         function($m) {
             return strtolower($m[0]);
         },
         'FIRST_SECOND_THIRD'
     );
```

Output:

```
First_Second_Third
```

---

Even simpler, use `mb_convert_case()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R3iLd))

```
echo mb_convert_case('FIRST_SECOND_THIRD', MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');
// First_Second_Third
```